# hyperledger composer runtime install options

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I need to change ports through which hyperledger composer installs runtime.  I found this link https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/composer.runtime.install.html where I can set the options, but I haven't found what's the format of this options. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a Fabric configured and running on different ports, it is the Business Network Card that specifies which Hosts and Ports are used by the composer runtime install command.

If you are building Cards yourself then you will specify the hosts and ports in a connection.json file.

If you need to modify an existing card you will find a file such as:
`/home/<user>/.composer/cards/<cardname>/connection.json` which specifies the hosts and ports of the Fabric.